# Update from React 15.6.2 to 16 Breaks Web Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, react-bootstrap

The current behavior is that none of my index.js is being rendered. When I use the react-scripts to build the web application in 16.2.0, I get an r.PropTypes is undefined error when I visit the localhost address. I presume this is because PropTypes is deprecated in 15.5 onwards and removed in 16, but I can't for the life of me figure out what is calling this. It's in some weird part of main.########.js after create-react-app builds it. I've tried updating all my other dependencies, but no dice once I update to React 16. The application works fine in 15.6.2.

I'm using NPM and here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "node-wf",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "create-react-app": "^1.5.2",
    "halogen": "^0.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-bootstrap-toggle": "^2.3.1",
    "react-contenteditable": "^2.0.7",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "react-split-pane": "^0.1.77",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^6.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/"
}
```

I'm also using some CDN scripts for jQuery, Bootstrap 3.3.7, Bootstrap toggle, and plotly. I'm not sure if there is a compatibility issue with those?

Comment: What are you using jQuery for in a React app, out of curiosity

Comment: Sorry, it's unreasonable for anyone to help you with this. You have posted your package.json and are asking to fix your entire project without code. If you can reduce your code to something manageable and ask "why doesn't this work in React 16" then it would be something that's more appropriate for SO

Comment: @KevinRaoofi that's a little harsh.

Comment: hey @D.B. you say you're getting this error after building. have you tried running it with the dev server instead? `npm start` ? you should get a better stacktrace to see where the error is coming from

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are having trouble finding the call that results in the error. Your browser's dev tools can be of great help: I know for sure that Chrome and Firefox include a "Pause on Uncaught Exceptions" button in their Source/Debugger tab respectively

[Screenshot for how that looks on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWeNb.png)

Once you have that option turned on, refresh your page and the debugger should pause when the exception is about to be thrown - then go through the call stack till you find the main caller in your source code. My guess will be that the culprit file is importing `PropTypes` from React instead of the prop-types package.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

azium made a good suggestion of ensuring that you are running the dev build by using `npm run start` - that should maintain clear source maps so that you can have a clearer stack trace and source code to look at

Comment: I definitely don't think this answer deserves a downvote. It doesn't really answer the question, but it's helpful. OP's problem doesn't sound super complicated, maybe he'll chime in and you can work together to figure it out and update your answer. good luck!

Comment: I would have went with a comment, but SO does not allow comments until a given number of reputation points (I dont get that to be honest haha). Thanks for the feedback though, I hope the OP will find this helpful :)